# Annotated relationships in Datomic

Tags: database-design, clojure, datomic, datalog

I was hoping to extend the conversation on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12444214/3100284) and get some more details in terms of implementation.

My requirements include allowing an admin to define tags on a relationship, the number of which is arbitrary, the entities involved are arbitrary, and the entities involved are not contingent (i.e. not a `Component` of the entity).

For a contrived example, a `User` can have many `Projects`. A `Project` can have many `Users`.

The admin creates an arbitrary number of tags to assign to related Users per relationship e.g. `Owner`, `Contributor`, `VIP`, etc. for `User` to `Project`.

From what I understand of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12480356/3100284), a simple `ref` is insufficient and I will need to create an additional entity, something like this-

Pertinent `Project` attribute

```
:db/ident              :project/associations
:db/valueType          :db.type/ref
:db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/many
```

Pertinent `User` attribute

```
:db/ident              :user/associations
:db/valueType          :db.type/ref
:db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/many
```

Pertinent `Association` attributes

```
:db/ident              :association/related-ents
:db/valueType          :db.type/string
:db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/many

:db/ident              :association/assoc-id
:db/valueType          :db.type/string
:db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one

:db/ident              :association/tag
:db/valueType          :db.type/ref
:db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
```

Pertinent `Tag` attribute

```
:db/ident              :tag/name
:db/valueType          :db.type/string
:db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
```

This is as far as I have gotten. I am not clear as to how to construct the `association` entity in an idiomatic-Datomic way.

To find associated relationships on a given `Project`, including but not limited to `Users`, as well as find relationships where `relationship tag = Contributor`, should I

- 1) Drop the `refs` on `Project` + `User` and retrieve the data via `Associations`? i.e. return all Associations where `association/related-ents` contains `User-Id = foo`
- 2) Something entirely different.

I suppose my question boils down to where do I store the `ref` for efficient look-ups? Is there a different `db.type` that should be used instead of `string`, or a different construct for the `association` that is needed? Are the `project/associations` and `user/associations` `refs` even necessary?

Appreciate any insight.

**Update**

---

After a bit more reflection, I think I tripped up on the `refs` on the various entities. I am wondering if I could simply have an `associations/relatedEnts` that is itself a ref that holds 2 Datomic db ids + tag and drop all of the other listed attrs. Is this ideal?

```
:db/ident              :association/relatedEnts
:db/valueType          :db.type/ref
:db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/many

:db/ident              :association/tag
:db/valueType          :db.type/ref
:db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
```

Comment: Did you consider specifying separate project attributes for each of the roles (for contributors, owners etc)?

Comment: Yes, I did consider that. That route loses the arbitrary flexibility of entity relationship. Again contrived, but for example, an admin comes along and decides to add a relationship between Project and Location to make it a treasure hunt. Possible tags would be `Starting Points`, `Lunch`, `Finish Line` or any number of arbitrary tags that could not be predicted up-front.

Comment: A new feature added to Datomic in June 2019 now adds an [additional option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682064/properties-on-datomic-ref-relationships/61406767#61406767https://) to this debate.

Answer (score 3):

When you're defining an entity to represent the relationship between two other entities (a `User` and a `Project` in your example), I'd recommend making the linkage from that reified relationship entity (your `Association`) to the other entities via Datomic references. This preserves the ability to navigate from one to the other without having to, for example, parse a compound string.

Additionally, your example suggests to me that you're considering only having a single `Association` entity to represent the relationship(s) between many `Users` and `Projects`. Although this approach can work, you will have much greater flexibility and potential for customization if you create an `Association` entity for every relationship you're modeling. If you prefer to think of this as a graph-modeling problem, your `User` and `Project` entities are nodes of the graph and you create an 'edge entity' for each edge between two nodes. Each of those 'edge entites' is represented by an instance of an `Association` that has two reference attributes, one to the `User` and one to the `Project`. Then that `Association` can also have as many arbitrary additional attributes as you want, allowing you to attach data directly to the relationship (i.e. for your tag attributes, or any other data you want to represent about the relationship).

Best,
Marshall

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I understand what you are saying. Could you update your answer with Datomic schema details?